# Keras multiple outputs, customed loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was trying to build a model with two inputs and two outputs. The structure of the model is like below.
And I would like to construct a customer loss function with two parts: the difference between 'd_flat' and 't_flat', and the categorical crossentropy loss of layer 'perdict'.  The model is like this:

```
initial_input_domain=tf.keras.Input(shape=(36,36,3))
initial_input_target=tf.keras.Input(shape=(36,36,3))

vgg_base=tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False,#weights='imagenet',
                                     input_shape=(36,36,3))

domain1=vgg_base(initial_input_domain)
target1=vgg_base(initial_input_target)

d_flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='d_flat')(domain1)
predictions=tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,name='predict', activation='sigmoid')(d_flat)

t_flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='t_flat')(target1)
predictions_t=tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes,name='predict_t', activation='sigmoid')(t_flat)

fin_model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=[initial_input_domain,initial_input_target], outputs=[predictions, predictions_t])
```

[image]

The loss function I wrote is like this:

```
def Total_loss(d_flat, t_flat):

    def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):

        Dist_LOSS = 'something does not matter' # the difference of two layers
        loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred) + Dist_LOSS
        return loss

    return loss_function
```

So my question is what is y_pred and y_true in this function? I only want this function to calculate the categorical crossentropy loss of 'predict', which is the left part. What should I do to make keras not calculate the categorical crossentropy loss of the right part? It seems like y_pred and y_true is the combination of the left and right branches. (The label I used for the right part is the correct label, I used for the right part is all 0, which means nothing)

Keras generates these outputs,

```
Epoch 1/100
6912/6912 [==============================] - 24s 3ms/sample - loss: 0.0315 - predict_loss: 0.0270 - predict_t_loss: 0.0045 - predict_categorical_accuracy: 0.9931 - predict_t_categorical_accuracy: 0.6413
```

It seems like the loss = predict_loss + predict_t_loss. It should be any predict_t_loss. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Custom loss functions can only work with `(y_true, y_pred)`. If you want to work with other variables that are defined *before* the final layer(s), like e.g. `d_flat, t_flat`, or only part of the output, you have to use [model.add_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#methods_2). As you can see in the API, you can either define it in your own custom layer (gives you more specific control) or on the model itself. In your case you can do something like this:

```
model.add_loss(d_flat - f_flat + K.categorical_crossentropy(predictions,y_pred_for_left_output)
```

where `y_pred_for_left_output` is the label tensor for this output node. This way you have defined the loss as the difference between the flat layers and the CE of the left output node only. You can adapt this to your  specific requirements but this would be the correct approach.

Comment: Thank you so much. But how do I extract y_pred_for_left_output  and predictions? Thank you.

Comment: @MH563 Each `Dense` layer has an output which is one of the two prediction values. `predictions.output` is the output provided by the network (y_pred) wheras y_true is the target provided as the input.